"which python" and "sys.path" give different outputs with conda env activated in VSCode
When I activate a conda env, select the corresponding interpreter and start Python in VScode everything seems fine at first glance :
   (My_env) name@my_computer:~/Bureau/My_env/Code/current_dir$       
   /home/name/anaconda3/envs/My_env/bin/python -m IPython --no-autoindent
   Python 3.12.4 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Jun 18 2024, 15:12:24) [GCC 11.2.0]
   Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
   IPython 8.12.3 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

sys.path and sys.version yield the corresponding interpreter. However, if I try which python or python --version in the terminal it refers to my default python version (corresponding to the base environment).
This strange behavior does not happen if I repeat the same process outside of VScode: which python and sys.path yield the same output.
Moreover, both inside and outside VScode, conda info shows the python version of the base env whatever env is activated.
Before removing conda auto-activation of base env I had two envs shown in my VScode terminal.
A few settings :
VScode
Version: 1.91.1
Commit: f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729
Date: 2024-07-09T22:08:12.169Z
Electron: 29.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 9728852
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156
Node.js: 20.9.0
V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.5.0-41-generic snap
Output of conda info :
     active environment : My_env
     active env location : /home/name/anaconda3/envs/My_env
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/name/.condarc
    populated config files : /home/name/.condarc
          conda version : 24.1.2
    conda-build version : 24.1.2
         python version : 3.11.7.final.0
                 solver : libmamba (default)
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=skylake
                          __conda=24.1.2=0
                          __glibc=2.35=0
                          __linux=6.5.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /home/name/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/name/anaconda3/etc/conda
     conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/name/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/name/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/name/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/name/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/24.1.2 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.7 Linux/6.5.0-41-generic
    ubuntu/22.04.4 glibc/2.35 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/24.1.0 libmambapy/1.5.6
    aau/0.4.3 c/o84sDdTYbleS3dVd3NF1Aw s/kgiszGL1njuqJYlZjLUa-w e/JXereckVRhPg5ZEODdeeVw
                UID:GID : 1001:1001
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

OS : Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, 64 bits
I tried to change the settings of conda (removing base env auto activation) which did not help.
I also tried hash -r as I've seen that it could influence the behavior of which but it did not help.

To ensure active your virtual environment in VSCode, you could try the following steps:

Select your virtual environment python interpreter by VSCode command Python: Select Interpreter.
Open your settings.json and add the following configuration to ensure that the terminal activates the Conda environment:

{
  "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
  "python.condaPath": "/path/to/anaconda3/bin/conda" 
}


You could also check your environment variables. Sometimes, environment variables can cause conflicts. Ensure that your PATH is properly set when the environment is activated. You can add an additional check in your .bashrc or .zshrc file:

    export PATH="/home/name/anaconda3/envs/My_env/bin:$PATH"

